# How to install gitlab-runner to CentOS/fedora

Tags: centos, fedora, rpm, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to install GitLab runner on the AWS server: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html

Linux distrib:

[image]

Linux arh:

```
Linux 4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64
```

So I downloaded .rpm file for CentOS:

```
sudo curl -LJO "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/rpm/gitlab-runner_x86_64.rpm"
```

But file isn't downloaded - only created with following content:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access
> Denied</Message><RequestId>8DA4057E392621C5</RequestId><Hos        
> tId>ehqGGAvJfAjryHQkQh06fmfRDuOX9bAeYYUZLTb6VZg4DkU2DPKRfYD5yv2fYhP0sz+rLlJkvo8=</HostId></Error>
```

How to properly install the gitlab-runner on the AWS server?

Answer (score 4):

Considering [`x86_64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#AMD64) is the name of a specific 64-bit [ISA (Instruction Set Architecture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) released in 1999 by AMD (Advanced Micro Devices), and later rebranded to **amd64**, I would rather download:

```
sudo curl -LJO "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/rpm/gitlab-runner_amd64.rpm"
```

I just tested it: it does download (62.4 MB).

Comment: "x86_64" is a conventional architecture code in much of the RPM world, but it appears that gitlab is determined to be unconventional.  That "amd64" is indeed the wanted code can be determined by following the instructions on the page linked by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You are not meant to download a file literally named "gitlab-runner_<arch>.rpm".  You are meant to replace the "<arch>" part with an appropriate code for the architecture of the machine on which you intend to install the software: probably "x86_64", but maybe "i686" or something else.

If you look in the file you downloaded or ask the `file` command to identify it, you will likely find that it contains the HTML of an error page, if it contains anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I updated the question. Can you comment on it?